# How to create a book title like this?

Tags: pdftex, titles

This is Roger Penrose' book The Road to Reality's title
[image: How to get a title like this?]

Currently my document begins like this,

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{varwidth}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usetikzlibrary{cd}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{appendix}
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \RequirePackage{fix-cm}

    \definecolor{bluegreen}{rgb}{-.2,.4,0.6}

    \newcommand\semihuge{\@setfontsize\semihuge{18.72}{20.38}}

    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\normalfont\huge}
        {\hspace*{-60pt}\thechapter.~#1}
        {-10pt}
        {\hspace*{-110pt}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+20pt\relax}{0pt}}
    \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]%conents
        {\normalfont\bfseries\huge}
        {\hspace*{175pt}#1}
        {-12pt}
        {\hspace*{-110pt}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+30pt\relax}{0pt}}
        \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}


    \geometry{
    top=20mm,
    total={145mm,230mm}
    }
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=bluegreen,
        filecolor=magenta,
        urlcolor=cyan,
        pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
        bookmarks=true,
    }
    \tikzset{>=stealth}

    \newcommand\BackgroundPic{
        \put(0,0){
            \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
                \vfill
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{BackGroundPDF.pdf}
                \vfill
            }}}




    \begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
    \end{titlepage}
    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \title{\Huge\textsc{The Road to Reality}}
    {}
    \date{}

    \maketitle
    \newpage


    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interletter space is defaulted to `\theLetterSpace`, but can be changed with optional argument to `\spaceout`.  *Additional* inter-word space is defined by `\theWordSpace`.  The rest is just using `\textsc`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{2\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{1.5in}
{\centering
\textsc{\Large\spaceout[5pt]{The Road to Reality}}

\hrulefill\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is altering the rest of the document even if i end the centering

Comment: @NiGGa I have edited the answer to limit the scope of the `\centering`.

Comment: Sorry for irritating but this has changed the style of table of contents,etc.

Comment: @NiGGa I would need to know more information about how you are trying to get what I provided, which has no reference to a table of contents, into a table of contents.

Comment: I have added my previous code.

Comment: @NiGGa If I take your code, and add my preamble definitions, and change the `\title` line to `\title{\Huge\textsc{\spaceout[5pt]{The Road to Reality}}}`, I detect no changes to the format of the table of contents.  In fact, the title is not even added to the toc.

Comment: How to get that underline? \hrulefill ?

Comment: @NiGGa In my case, I got the underline with an `\hrulefill` that occurs in a paragraph by itself.   Depending on the application, one may need a `\noindent\hrulefill`.  But the key is to not have text before or after it, or such text will appear on the same line as the rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31811/discussion-between-nigga-and-steven-b-segletes).