# Create a macro to add space between letters

Tags: spacing

I'm looking for a way to have the following result:

```
\addspaces{some text} % Output: S O M E   T E X T
```

I found a first way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951392/latex-space-after-every-letter

However, this method only work for one word. It doesn't add more space between the end of "some" and the start of "text" in my example. (output = S O M E T E X T). Second problem, this doesn't compile if I put it in a class document.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62346/enlarging-tracking-letter-spacing could help.

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/capital-letter-expanded-letter-space-kerning or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279000/how-to-create-a-book-title-like-this

Comment: Solved with the following answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279000/how-to-create-a-book-title-like-this